# creating a join table in rails; when adding indices should not they be two way

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In docs and also on SO (although I could not find the link(s) again), there is the really helpful tip not to forget to create index for a join table.

like this one

> Don’t forget to add indexes to HATM table:
>
> add_index :developers_projects, [:developer_id, :project_id]

found here [API DOC](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many)

but shouldn't be there something like

```
add_index :developers_projects, [:developer_id, :project_id]
add_index :developers_projects, [:project_id]
```

at least as a tip in some cases, when coming from the other side? Or do I again miss Rails and that happens automaticaly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To some extent it may depend on the database and version.

If a database allows index-only scans then if you want to find all projects per developer *and* all developers per project then  create indexes:

```
add_index :developers_projects, [:developer_id, :project_id]
add_index :developers_projects, [:project_id  ,:developer_id]
```

If the table must always be touched by the database anyway (older versions of PostgreSQL) then:

```
add_index :developers_projects, :developer_id
add_index :developers_projects, :project_id
```

... although as you may be upgrading to a version that supports index-only access later on you'd be justified in creating the first version anyway, in the name of future-proofing.

Answer (score 0):

A multi-column index is all you typically need here, as they do work 'two-way'. In fact, in a HABTM relationship, there are three ways to hit a two column index.

In your case...

1. Querying for a 'project_id = 1' will ask the INDEX for all
   'developers_projects' records that have 'project_id = 1'
2. Querying
   for a 'developer_id = 1' will ask the INDEX for all
   'developers_projects' records that have 'developer_id = 1'
3. Querying
   for 'project_id = 1 AND developer_id = 1' will ask the INDEX for all
   'developers_projects' records that have both 'project_id = 1' AND
   'developer_id = 1'

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Which RDBMSs support index access by only non-leading columns?

Comment: Yeah - all depends on the DB. For instance, if you are running MySQL - try using the EXPLAIN syntax to determine which INDEX your queries are using. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html Other DB's have similar tools that you can use to determine the types of indexes that best suit your queries.

Comment: You may be correct that MySQL can use non-leading columns of an index, but PostgreSQL doesn't, and nor does Oracle (well, except for skip-scans). So if this advice is correct (tbh, I doubt that it is for b-tree indexes) then it applies only to a subset of databases